# I modified my inittab file and I think I bricked my embedded linux card

Tags: debian

I have a TS-7200 sbc card from Technologic Systems running linux and I am trying to modify the inittab file so it logs in as root and automatically runs my application. I obviously did something wrong in the inittab file because now when I reboot it I get:

```
INIT: version 2.85-ts1.00 booting
INIT: /etc/inittab[72]: duplicate ID field "ca"
INIT: cannot execute "/etc/init.d/rcS"
INIT: Entering runlevel: 3
INIT: cannot execute "/etc/init.d/rc"
INIT: Id "gel" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
INIT: no more processes left in this runlevel
```

Then I keep getting the last 2 lines every 5 minutes and can't ctrl-c out of it. (or ctrl-d).

I can't think of anything other than to reflash the card. (which I don't know how to do yet).

Here's the inittab file:

```
# Runlevels. The runlevels used by RedHatSystems are:
#   0 - halt (DO_NOT set initdefault to this)
#   1 - Maintaince (single user) mode. 
#   2 - Multiuser, no networking support 
#   3 - Full multiuser mode
#   4 - No standard. Used for weird/special runlevel 
#   5 - Full multiuser with fbdev text console started
#   6 - reboot (DO_NOT set initdefault to this)
# 

# Default Runlevel to Go into
dflt:3:initdefault:

# System Startup. Do these process before
# anything else 
strt::sysinit:/etc/rc.d/rcS.sysinit
#smpl::sysinit:/path/to/process

# Process to do for each specific Runlevel
#smpl:4:actionkeyword:/path/to/process arguments
r0:0:wait:/etc/rc.d/rcS 0
r1:1:wait:/etc/rc.d/rcS 1
r2:2:wait:/etc/rc.d/rcS 2
r3:3:wait:/etc/rc.d/rcS 3
r4:4:wait:/etc/rc.d/rcS 4
r5:5:wait:/etc/rc.d/rcS 5
r6:6:wait:/etc/rc.d/rcS 6
# Things to run once specified runlevel is entered
#ud::once:/sbin/update
#
# Start console logins on both COM Ports
#
#lgn0:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyAM0 
#lgn1:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyAM1 
go0:2345:wait:/sbin/mingetty --autologin root ttyAM0 linux
ge1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty ttyAM0 linux

#
# Start Virtual Terminal Logins
#
#vty1:5:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 vc/0
###vty2::respawn:/sbin/mingetty vc/2

# Trap CTRL-ALT-DELETE
ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Comment: I could do an ftp but I don't think its at the point in the init.d scripts where it starts the network.

Comment: Also Jp1 lets you boot from the comport instead of flash.

Comment: The contents of said inittab would be helpful. Clearly the gel and ca entries are problematic.

Comment: Do you have an idea why this `duplicate ID field "ca"` message is displayed when there is only one line with ID `ca:` in the file? And what Debian system are you using (Wheezy aready supported systemd, since Jessie it's the default IIRC, so why do you have an `iniittab` at all?)?

Comment: I think what I may have done was to do an echo "ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -r now" >> inittab thinking it wasn't in there. I just got careless.

Comment: It's a fairly old card and there's a procedure to update the OS which I haven't had any success at.

Comment: [this](https://wiki.embeddedarm.com/wiki/TS-7200#Loading_an_Executing_a_Kernel) wiki says the board has a monitor you can enter by typing Ctrl-C within 1 second of power on. You can then edit the boot parameters to add the Linux option `S`  which should boot you to single user mode.

Comment: that wiki doesn't say anything about a linux option S. When you hit Ctrl-C you go into Redboot which allows you to edit the boot parameters which are fis load vmlinux and then exec -c "console=ttyAM0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock1" I tried exec -S and get an error

Comment: the help menu says for 'exec' there's an option -c "kernel command line"

Comment: You can try `exec -c "S console=ttyAM0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock1"` as it seems this string is what is passed to the kernel.

Comment: Thanks meuh - that seems to work. Now I just have to fix the inittab file.